# Sorting an array of JSON objects by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have this JSON array of objects by an API call and I want to sort it by date. But the date format is in ISO and i am new to javascript so i don't know how to convert it and then sort it.

```
  "statuses": [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-31T05:57:32.143Z",
      "status": "Awaiting Pickup"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-30T07:55:08.033Z",
      "status": "Dispatched"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-18T07:55:08.033Z",
      "status": "Parcel Assigned to Rider for Delivery"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-12T07:55:08.033Z",
      "status": "Delivered"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-24T07:55:08.033Z",
      "status": "Returned"
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to covert them. ISO date strings sort properly as strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sort`. For conversion you can use `new Date()`

```js
var obj={ "statuses": [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-31T05:57:32.143Z",
      "status": "Awaiting Pickup"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-30T07:55:08.033Z",
      "status": "Dispatched"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-18T07:55:08.033Z",
      "status": "Parcel Assigned to Rider for Delivery"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-12T07:55:08.033Z",
      "status": "Delivered"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-24T07:55:08.033Z",
      "status": "Returned"
    }
  ],
}
obj.statuses.sort((a,b)=>new Date(a.date)-new Date(b.date))
console.log(obj)
```